# How to dynamically sort elements and save multiple changes on submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sorting, submit

I have this view with a receipe that has many ingredients. I want to be able to dynamically sort my ingredients and only send the changes to the controller once, when hitting the submit button for the whole form. I've been googling this for quite a while and I do see many question regarding this, though not any answers... I'm quite familiar with rails, but just starting out with javascript.

View

```
<% form_for @receipe do |r| %>  
  <%= r.text_field.name %>  
  <% f.fields_for :receipe_ingredients do |ri| %>  
    <%= ri.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>  
      <%= link_to i.object.name, ingredient_path(i.object.id) %>  
      <%= ri.text_field :specification %>  
    <% end %>  
  <% end %>  
<%= r.submit "save" %>  
<% end %>  
<%= link_to "add more ingredients", ingredients %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you are using jquery or prototype. I assume Prototype, check this:

http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/sortable-lists-demo/

Comment: I'm using rails 2 so prototype would be the default. I'm conserned about using something that works, and at this pint of time I don't know which of prototype or jquery is more solid / less hacky

Comment: @svei: both prototype+scriptaculous and jquery are great libraries, and their Sortable class are equally powerful. But being Prototype the default shipped with Rails, it's the best option till you gain some experience.

Comment: Tokland might be right about that. If you're not more experienced with either jQuery or Prototype, than you should probably use Prototype just because it ships with Rails. The solution I offered should not be any harder with Prototype than it is with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Place the ingredients in a list, than use javascript to make them sortable. [This seems llike a good plugin for that.](http://www.wil-linssen.com/musings/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/)

Than on submit, block the usual reloading of the page with something like

```
$("#submit").preventDefault();
```

and send the data in the javascript array to your rails app with ajax. Compare the old order on the server with the new order in the javascript array, and make the adjustments to their order. I think that should help.

I you don't want to use ajax, load the javascript array in a hidden textfield in json format every time the user changes the order, and make your controller work with that json string to find out the order of the items.

Comment: "I you don't want to use ajax, load the javascript array in a hidden textfield in json format every time the user changes the order, and make your controller work with that json string to find out the order of the items."
    
I think this is the way to go for my application. I want the form to be submitted as a whole.

Comment: Well than you should try that;) If you take a look at the demo of the plugin I suggested you'll see that it displays the JavaScript array if you drag and drop. You could take this demo and modify it to put the data in a hidden field instead of a visible div, and voila. I'm curious if it works out, please let me know:)

Comment: I'm going to look into prototype/scriptaculous then. For traceability this post is in relation to my previous question here (my goal is to be able to edit and submit to server once, as simple as possible): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641054/javascript-submit-multiple-attribute-changes-to-controller-ruby-on-rails